# add event listner is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im trying to add an event listener to a button so when its pressed it can add a value into a container.

```
<div className="grid-container">
            <div>
            <button id="redBet" className="redButton" onclick={this.handleBetsRed}>Place Red</button>
            <div id="redSearch" class="ui search">
              <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Common passwords..." />
                <div class="results">
                  <p className="para"></p>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The Button is inside the above code with the onclick to run the function below:

```
handleBetsRed = () => {
    document.getElementsByClassName("redButton").addEventListener("click", () => {
      console.log("Yeet")
    })
  
  }
```

this function is not inside any function and right above the render, return statements.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns a nodeList not a single element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Comment: Consider not using querySelector at all when using react. It’s not necessary. Use a ref instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

there are two issues,

#### 1:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("redButton")
```

Here, [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns `HTMLCollection` containing matched Nodes, Not a single on. So, U probably wanna do something like this,

```
document.getElementsByClassName("redButton")[0]
```

Or, U may use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector),

```
document.querySelector(".redButton")
```

#### 2:

```
 <button id="redBet" className="redButton" onclick={this.handleBetsRed}>Place Red</button>
```

Here, `onclick` did u mean `onClick`

Comment: Hiya, this question has a duplicate. Please may you flag it as such?

Answer (score -1):

replace `onclick` with `onClick` in the `redButton`, and remove the `getElementsByClassName` from the click handler function

```
<div className="grid-container">
  <div>
    <button id="redBet" className="redButton" onClick={this.handleBetsRed}>Place Red</button>
    <div id="redSearch" class="ui search">
      <input class="prompt" type="text" placeholder="Common passwords..." />
        <div class="results">
          <p className="para"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
handleBetsRed = () => {
  console.log("Yeet")
}
```

Comment: This question has a duplicate. Please may you flag it as such?